# How to give controller sass files precedence over sass imported from application.scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm having an issue in that inside my controllers scss file, I continually have to mark everything with `!important` in order to style elements. Here's an example input element in my `Map` controllers scss:

```
.search-field {
    width: 300px !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 15px !important;
}
```

This is because inside `application.scss`, I imported my material library which takes precedence over `map.scss`:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
 @import "materialize";
 @import "font-awesome";
 * {
     font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 }

 html {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
 body {
     margin: 0;
     min-width: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     background-color: #1A1A1A;
 }
```

How can I avoid having to use the `!important` flag everywhere?

### EDIT:

I have also tried the following (with no luck)

inside `application.html.erb` I added an additional link to my controllers css

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'map', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

then removed the use of `require_tree .` inside application.scss

When I restarted the server however, I still needed the !important tags. Still no luck

Comment: What about adding `@import "map";` underneath your others (+ a restart)?

Comment: Rails assets are loaded in order so you can set precedence by changing the order of style tags in your layout.

Comment: Could you use a more specific selector?

Comment: @bkunzi01 Not sure how that would help me considering I use a single statement: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

Comment: Instead of including them in your `application.scss` you could individually call these files in the head of your layout file. Call them before your `application.scss` script tag to ensure it takes priority over these imports

Comment: You don't have two lines?  One for application.scss and then one in your layouts below/above it for adding the related controller sass file?

Comment: @bkunzi01 I don't since the `application.scss` file has `require tree .` in it's top line. I guess I shouldn't be doing this? This was the default configuration given to me by rails

Comment: Update: I attempted to split the stylesheets into seperate css files but got nowhere. Still need to use my `!important` tags

Comment: Ahhh Ok I thought you were importing your controllers separately!  I'll post an answer below on how I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's very rare to need every stylesheet in your application to be loaded on every page, you'll find importing only what's necessary per page to be much more efficient, shorten load times, and also address the problem of which styles take precedence!  The Rails way to do this is to remove the `require tree` statements in your `/application.js` and `/application.scss` files.  The only files imported in your application.js & application.scss files should be app-wide styles or js.  Then you would add the following lines to your `layouts/application.html.erb` file:

Inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] if Rails.application.assets_manifest.assets["#{params[:controller]}.css"]
```

This will then include the corresponding controller's stylesheets.  Putting this before or after the stylesheet_link_tag for your application changes the precedence based upon your needs.

Then in your `<body>` tag you should add:

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] if Rails.application.assets_manifest.assets["#{params[:controller]}.js"]
```

Now, to make this work in production for deploying your app you'll need to add the controller names to your `config/initializers/assets.rb` file or else you'll get an error that the assets weren't compiled.  In that file you'll add as follows for your map controller:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( maps.js )

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( maps.css) #Note rails expects the css suffix and not the scss suffix here so use that and not scss even though your file may be maps.scss
```

Then everytime you add a new controller in the future, add that controller's name to the arrays shown above and then run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and you're good to go.  For more examples checkout my old answer on basically the same problem here: [sprockets loads sass in random order with twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880773/sprockets-loads-sass-in-random-order-with-twitter-bootstrap/39881617#39881617)

Comment: This should have more upvotes. There are so many incomplete answers on similar questions with dozens or hundreds of likes.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a combination of lower priority css rules added onto the asset pipeline loading order. I found my problem was solver when I did the following to my `application.scss` file:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require materialize
 *= require_tree .
 */

 * {
     font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 }

 html {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
 body {
     margin: 0;
     min-width: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     background-color: #1A1A1A;
 }
```

I could remove most `!important` rules afterwards, and found that I was using a class css rule but it was being overrode by a specific `input[type=text]` rule, using an ID instead let me make the changes I wanted to.